# Responsive footer with a few images in divs

Tags: html, css

I have a Wordpress site. I have altered the footer to contain five divs with images in them.

This is the **html** code for the footer:

```
<footer class="site-footer">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="logo-gallery">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="link"><img src="image_url"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="link"><img src="image_url"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="link"><img src="image_url"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="link"><img src="image_url"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="link"><img src="image_url"></a>
                </div><!-- .logo -->
            </div><!-- .logo-gallery -->
        </div><!-- .table -->
    </footer>
```

For **css** I came up with this:

```
/* Footer */  
.site-footer {
    background-color: #e8e5ce;
    /*min-height: 180px;*/
}

.site-footer .table {
    display: table;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-footer .logo-gallery {
    display: table-row;
}

.site-footer .logo {
    display: table-cell;    
}
```

On a desktop computer the images now show as I would like them to:
1. they take up to 80% of the width (so that they are closer to eachother)
2. they are (as a group) placed at the center of the screen horizontally.

I want to make the images fit a smaller screen (a cell phone or tablet) - right now I get a horizontal scroll bar when I try to downsize the browser window and the images are beyong the right edge of the window (I haven't checked this code with a phone yet).

On the smaller screen I would like them either to get smaller to fit the width (all five) or appear underneath eachother (with the background color stretched underneath).

I also have a **second version of css**. Here, the problem is that the images clump up when downsizing the browser window (and also on the phone: check here: http://npozp.pl/)

```
/* Footer */

.site-footer {
    background-color: #e8e5ce;
    min-height: 180px;
}

.site-footer .logo-gallery {
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.site-footer .logo {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 30px 15px;
}
```

I am looking for a way to do this, it can be one of the above codes fix or please suggest an approach that I could take.

Thanks for reading! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using media queries so that you can manipulate your layout using the pixel size of the device.

Your css adjustments should look like:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
   .site-footer .logo {
   width: 100%;
  }
}
```

As you can see the mix and max device width values can be changed and you can add multiple media queries to get the best out of your layout.